# Rails server not starting with Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I am trying to deploy a Ruby on Rails project using docker, but am having some issues. My Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    gem install --no-document rails -v 5.2.3

COPY ./Gemfile ./Gemfile.lock ./
COPY ./.gemrc ~/

RUN printf "gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri --no-document" | tee /etc/gemrc ~/.gemrc && \
    gem install bundler -v '2.1.4'
RUN bundle install --jobs 2

COPY . .

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/bin
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["rails", "server", "puma"]
```

and `docker-entrypoint.sh` is used to ensure the server does not reuse a pid and looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

if [ -f tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
  rm tmp/pids/server.pid
fi

exec bundle exec "$@"
```

The image builds successfully with `docker build -t rails_app` , but when I run it with `docker run -p 3000:3000 rails_app`, no errors are thrown, but no output is shown to the screen. Then when I hit Control-C to stop the container, it gives me the output of the puma server starting then stops itself.

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 rails_app
^C=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.4.2 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.4 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
- Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
=== puma shutdown: 2020-04-19 21:42:28 +0000 ===
Goodbye!
Exiting
```

What needs to be done for the container to start the server before I close the container? Additionally, before hitting Control-C nothing is found at localhost:3000 so the server has not started silently.